# Pandas - Add a new calculated column to a MultiIndex column dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a Dataframe with the following structure:

```
np.random.seed(1)
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[3, 5], ["X","Y","V","T"]], names=["Node", "Parameter"])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2022-07-07 12:00:00', '2022-07-07 13:00:00',
               '2022-07-07 14:00:00', '2022-07-07 15:00:00',
               '2022-07-07 16:00:00'],
             dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None), columns=mi, data=np.random.rand(5,8))

print(df)
Node                        3                                       5
Parameter                   X         Y         V         T         X         Y         V         T
Date
2022-07-07 12:00:00  0.417022  0.720324  0.000114  0.302333  0.146756  0.092339  0.186260  0.345561
2022-07-07 13:00:00  0.396767  0.538817  0.419195  0.685220  0.204452  0.878117  0.027388  0.670468
2022-07-07 14:00:00  0.417305  0.558690  0.140387  0.198101  0.800745  0.968262  0.313424  0.692323
2022-07-07 15:00:00  0.876389  0.894607  0.085044  0.039055  0.169830  0.878143  0.098347  0.421108
2022-07-07 16:00:00  0.957890  0.533165  0.691877  0.315516  0.686501  0.834626  0.018288  0.750144
```

I would like to add a new calculated column "Z" for each Node, based on the value "X" ** 2 + "Y" ** 2.

The following achieves the desired result:

```
x = df.loc[:,(slice(None),"X")]
y = df.loc[:,(slice(None),"Y")]
z = (x**2).rename(columns={"X":"Z"}) + (y ** 2).rename(columns={"Y":"Z"})
result = df.join(z).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Is there a more straightforward way to achieve this?
For example, using `df.xs` to select the desired column data e.g. `df.xs("X", axis=1, level=1) **2 + df.xs("X", axis=1, level=1) ** 2`, how can I then assign the result to the original dataframe?

Comment: what is x? there is no reference to it in your solution

Comment: @sammywemmy question edited to show definition of x

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
(df.groupby(level='Node', axis=1)
   .apply(lambda g: g.droplevel('Node', axis=1).eval('Z = X**2 + Y**2'))
 )
```

Or, with [`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) and `drop_level=False` on one of the values:

```
(df.join((df.xs('X', axis=1, level=1, drop_level=False)**2
         +df.xs('Y', axis=1, level=1)**2
         ).rename(columns={'X': 'Z'}, level=1)
        )
   .sort_index(axis=1, level=0, sort_remaining=False)
 )
```

Output:

```
Node                        3                                                 5                                        
Parameter                   X         Y         V         T         Z         X         Y         V         T         Z
Date                                                                                                                   
2022-07-07 12:00:00  0.417022  0.720324  0.000114  0.302333  0.692775  0.146756  0.092339  0.186260  0.345561  0.030064
2022-07-07 13:00:00  0.396767  0.538817  0.419195  0.685220  0.447748  0.204452  0.878117  0.027388  0.670468  0.812891
2022-07-07 14:00:00  0.417305  0.558690  0.140387  0.198101  0.486278  0.800745  0.968262  0.313424  0.692323  1.578722
2022-07-07 15:00:00  0.876389  0.894607  0.085044  0.039055  1.568379  0.169830  0.878143  0.098347  0.421108  0.799977
2022-07-07 16:00:00  0.957890  0.533165  0.691877  0.315516  1.201818  0.686501  0.834626  0.018288  0.750144  1.167884
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with `pd.xs`:

```py
out = df.xs('X',axis=1,level=1).pow(2).add(df.xs('Y',axis=1,level=1).pow(2))
out.columns = [out.columns, np.repeat(['Z'], 2)]
pd.concat([df, out], axis = 1).sort_index(axis=1)
Node                        3                                                 5                                        
Parameter                   T         V         X         Y         Z         T         V         X         Y         Z
Date                                                                                                                   
2022-07-07 12:00:00  0.302333  0.000114  0.417022  0.720324  0.692775  0.345561  0.186260  0.146756  0.092339  0.030064
2022-07-07 13:00:00  0.685220  0.419195  0.396767  0.538817  0.447748  0.670468  0.027388  0.204452  0.878117  0.812891
2022-07-07 14:00:00  0.198101  0.140387  0.417305  0.558690  0.486278  0.692323  0.313424  0.800745  0.968262  1.578722
2022-07-07 15:00:00  0.039055  0.085044  0.876389  0.894607  1.568379  0.421108  0.098347  0.169830  0.878143  0.799977
2022-07-07 16:00:00  0.315516  0.691877  0.957890  0.533165  1.201818  0.750144  0.018288  0.686501  0.834626  1.167884
```

Another option, is to select all the columns, run `pow` across all the columns in one go, before grouping and concatenating:

```py
out = (df
      .loc(axis=1)[:, ['X','Y']]
      .pow(2)
      .groupby(level='Node', axis=1)
      .agg(np.add.reduce,axis=1))
out.columns = [out.columns, np.repeat(['Z'], 2)]
pd.concat([df, out], axis = 1).sort_index(axis=1)
```